# The easiest way to check the difference in DOM and css because of javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

What's the easiest way to check using the browser the difference in DOM and css **on the whole page** after some events happened (let's say you've clicked on the button).
Google Chrome would be the preferable browser for this purpose.

Again, with another words:

You have a page.
You did something on the page (clicked the button) and the page (DOM and css) was changed by javascript.
What was changed in DOM and css? How to figure it out without debugging javascript?

Comment: This question is either too broad, ***opinion based*** or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Comment: Is this the worst question ever on Stackoverflow ? Dude, what do you mean ?

Comment: @punkbit , I've updated the question for you. Thank you.

Comment: Maybe  [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) is helpful there.

Comment: Check the event handler for that click event, see what it does; when the event is triggered, you know what happened on the page. No hocus pocus!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Difference between DOM and css is a bad wording, since they are two completely different things. Even when my DOM is empty, all the css still applies.

If you want to detect changes in your DOM in general you should probably have a look at [React.js](https://facebook.github.io/react/). The idea is you create a virtual DOM. After you edited the DOM with JS you can compare it to your virtual DOM to see the differences.